# Show more than (or less than) six recent projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, vssettings

Is it possible to change the number of recent project showing on the start page of Visual Studio 2010, and if so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Tools >> Options..., click on Environment, and change the Recent Files setting as desired, neato! I didn't even know this was an option until today. [image]

Comment: This works for Visual Studio 2008 as well, if you have the misfortune of not being able to use 2010 yet (2008 is terrific, it's just that 2010 is better).

Comment: This works for Visual Studio 2012 also. Microsoft didn't see fit to fix something that wasn't broken, good for them.

Comment: And VS 2015. Maximum number of items is 24.

Answer (score 0):

Tools, Options, General, Recent Files